# Finding difference less than the average in an unsorted array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I need to find 2 elements in an unsorted array such that the difference between them is less than or equal to (Maximum - Minimum)/(number of elements in the array).

In O(n).

I know the max and min values.

Can anyone think of something?

Thank you!

Comment: @Binary Worrier: what diffrence does it make? ;-)

Comment: @splattne a lot, but it means at least a retag

Comment: @Greg Dean: oh, that is the DIFFRENCE! ;-)

Comment: @Splattne: Part of my job is to mentor junior programmers at different levels. Just providing a complete answer does the learner little good. If it's homework, I'll give helpful suggestions on how to solve the problem, without giving a full solution. Also +1 Greg Dean, it should be retagged

Comment: So, it's okay to correct the title "diffrence" myself and the other spelling mistakes. No one will understand my "funny" comment then. ;-)

Comment: Oops, completely missed that, I'm very tired today, sorry Splattne :)

Comment: What if no solution exists? For instance, the array {3, 4} has max = 4, min = 3, n = 2, and no pair of elements has difference less than or equal to (4-3)/2 = 0.5

Comment: @onebyone: By definition there's always one pair of numbers that solve the problem

Comment: So what's the solution in the case I give, where the array is {3,4}? It's certainly not "3 and 4", since their difference is 1, which is greater than the stated bound. I believe that the problem has been stated incorrectly. Unless you mean "they wouldn't give you an input array with no solution".

Comment: There is a very slightly different problem which I think might be the intended one, where there is guaranteed to be a solution, and the way you prove that there's a solution also provides an O(n) algorithm for finding it. It involves pigeons.

Comment: @onebyone: feck, you're right. As stated before I am very tired today, and not thinking clearly I was indeed thinking of 3 & 4 (the shame). Honest question. Is my hint below any use? I'm past the point of being able to tell, if it's not I'll remove it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack: I may have steered you wrong mate, a thousand apologies if I have. I'll think about this a little more, it's an interesting problem. I have deleted my answer. Thanks also to onebyone

Comment: Depends what the question is supposed to be, but I suspect that what you've said doesn't lead to a solution. Certainly it doesn't lead to the solution I have in mind for the question I have in mind, but I could easily be on the wrong track.

Comment: @jack can you please provide some example input data and an expected solution? I agree with @onebyone a solution does not seems possible.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Use [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).  Don't sort the individual buckets.

Should be pretty obvious what to do from here, and how to size the buckets.

Comment: This is the correct solution. I'm not sure about "pretty obvious", the one thing to worry about is there are two situations to check: one where one pidgeonhole has more than one pidgeon, and one where all pidgeonholes have exactly 1 pidgeon.

Comment: Sid Datta goes into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

1. Number of buckets = `2n`.

   values in each bucket = `(min + k((max-min)/2n)) <= value < (min + (k+1)((max-min)/2n)).`

   0 <= k < 2n

   Range of each bucket = `((max-min)/2n)`
2. Assign each element into buckets. Dont sort inside buckets.
3. If any bucket has more than 1 element, the maximum possible difference between them is `((max-min)/2n)` . Hence you have your answer.
4. If any two consecutive buckets have more than zero elements each, maximum difference between them is `((max-min)/2n)*2 = ((max-min)/n)` . Hence you have your answer.

Comment: this works, although you can make do with n buckets, you just have to compare consecutive values.

Comment: I think this misses the solution in some cases. What if the n items appear in alternate buckets, so there are never two non-empty buckets in a row, but there's one value near the "top" of bucket j, and another value near the "bottom" of bucket j+2. They're less than (max-min)/n apart.

Comment: As Jimmy says, though, in this case the buckets have fully sorted the array, meaning that you can finish with an O(n) pass to either find a solution or prove there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

The correct question should be: 
in an array A=[a0,a2,..an] find two elements a, b such that the difference between them is less than or equal to: (M-m)/n > | a - b| where M=max(A) and m = min(A).

The solution I’ll suggest is using quickSelect, time complexity of O(n) in expectation.  it’s actual worst case is O(n^2). This is a tradeoff because most times it's O(n), but it demand O(1) space complexity (if quickSelect is implemented iteratively and my pseudo code is implemented with a while loop instead of recursion).

**main idea:** 
At each iteration we find the median using quickSelect, if `|max - medianValue | > |min - medianValue |` we know that we should search to the left side of the array. That is because we have the same amount of elements at both side, but the median value is closer to the minimum thus there should be elements with smaller difference between them.  Else we should search at the right side.

each time we do that we know the new maximum or minimum of the subArray should be the median. 
we continue the search, each time dividing the array’s size by 2.

**proof of runtime in expectation:** 
assume each iteration over n elements take c*n + d in expectation. 
thus we have:

(c*n + d)  + 0.5*(c*n + d) + 0.25* (c*n + d) + … +(1/log_{2}(n)) *(c*n + d) <=

<=(1+0.5+0.25+….)d + (c*n + 0.5*c*n +….) = (1+0.5+0.25+….)d + c*n(1+0.5+0.25+….) =

=2*d +2*c*n

meaning we have O(n) in expectation.

**pseudo-code using recursion:**

```
run(arr):
   M = max(arr)
   m = min(arr)
   return findPairBelowAverageDiff(arr,0,arr.length,m,M)

findPairBelowAverageDiff(arr, start, end,  min,  max) :
      if start + 1 < end:
            medianPos = start + (end - start) / 2
         // median that is between start and end in the arr.
            quickSelect(arr,  start,  medianPos,  end)
            if max - arr[medianPos] > arr[medianPos] - min:
                return findPairBelowAverageDiff(arr, start, medianPos, 
                                min, arr[medianPos])
            else :
                return findPairBelowAverageDiff(arr, medianPos, 
                                        end, arr[medianPos], max);
       else :
            return (arr[start],  arr[start + 1])
```